# Origine della 'stecca'

Tags: word-usage, etymology

Da dove deriva il termine ***[stecca](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stecca/)*** comunemente usato in referimento a:

> - (gerg). Compenso illecitamente dato o ottenuto in cambio di determinati favori, mazzetta.

Deriva da uno dei comuni significati di stecca o ha un'origine completamente diversa?

Answer (score 1):

'stecca' nasce nel dopoguerra dal linguaggio dei marittimi che, per piccoli imbrogli, venivano ricompensati con una 'stecca' di sigarette.

Comment: Lo immagini? L'hai letto da qualche parte? Facevi il marittimo nel dopoguerra? :-)

Comment: L'ho imparato da mio nonno quando, molti anni fa, lo raccontava come aneddoto.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider - interessante, ma tuttalpiù vale come aneddoto che come risposta.

Answer (score 0):

Josh, come riporta il dizionario che hai citato è una espressione gergale, di tipo cosiddetto "coatto" (per dirla con un altro termine gergale). L'origine di questi termini non è dotta e in certi casi si tratta di espressioni completamente prive di significato, che si usano come sono e per quel che sono. È un po' come chiedersi il significato di "sdrenare" o "sdrumare".

Comment: Già, ma anche se non sono termini dotti, un'origine la avranno, no? Non è che i “coatti” scelgono lettere a caso, le giustappongono e cominciano a usarle.

Comment: E se “sdrenare” è lo stesso di “sderenare”, un'origine ce l'ha eccome: vedi [qui](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sderenare/). C'entra con i reni.

Comment: correggo "sgrumare", sostituendo con "sdrumare".